# Entity Framework Core - 2 Contexts in the same database - Second context tables are not created

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use 2 contexts on the same database.
To create the database I'm using `DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated()`
The first `EnsureCreated` call works fine, the second `EnsureCreated` call does not work.

**Some considerations**

Profiling SQL Server I can see that EF Core checks for the existence of a table

```
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
        WHERE 
            TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE') 

    SELECT 1 
ELSE 
    SELECT 0
```

then it runs the create table statement.
If there is a user table on the DB nothing is done...

Is there a way to force table creations from entities scaffolding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I found only this way.

```
RelationalDatabaseCreator databaseCreator = 
    (RelationalDatabaseCreator) context.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>();
databaseCreator.CreateTables();
```

Comment: What about InMemoryDatabaseCreator?

Comment: What if you have multiple `DbContext`s, each for its separate database schema AND there are cross-schema references between tables with foreign keys? You would have to call `CreateTables()` on both `DbContext`s, but because there are cross-schema references between them, it would try to create the same table two times which results in an exception.

Comment: @samcarlson, did you find a solution to that issue?

Comment: @SoraTeichman Take a look at this GitHub issue: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30844#issuecomment-1539946766

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because I failed to run `add-migration SecondContext_Initial -Context SecondContext` so there was no migration to run.  Both `EnsureCreated()` (returned false) and `Migrate()` (did nothing) failed to yield any clues to my neglect.